# What are the inappropriateness of incremental algorithm for line drawing by illustrating two key features

Tags: graphics, 3d

What are the inappropriateness of incremental algorithm for line drawing by illustrating two key features***

### strong text

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In incremental algorithm, We may have to Round to get points. It
  takes more time.
- Need special algorithm for vertical lines. (slope --> infinity)